# Problem with recursive method for BST rRemove(BSTNode<T> current, T data, BSTNode<T> dummy) when using pointer reinforcement technique

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Here is the Node class:

```
public class BSTNode<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

private T data;
private BSTNode<T> left;
private BSTNode<T> right;

BSTNode(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

T getData() {
    return data;
}

BSTNode<T> getLeft() {
    return left;
}

BSTNode<T> getRight() {
    return right;
}

void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

void setLeft(BSTNode<T> left) {
    this.left = left;
}

void setRight(BSTNode<T> right) {
    this.right = right;
}
```

}

Here is my BST class with main driver method:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class BST<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

private BSTNode<T> root;
private int size;

BST() {
    root = null;
}

public void add(T data) {
    if (data == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: Data can't be null");
    }
    root = rAdd(root, data);
}

private BSTNode<T> rAdd(BSTNode<T> current, T data) {
    if (current == null) {
        size++;
        return new BSTNode<T>(data);
    } else if (data.compareTo(current.getData()) < 0) {
        current.setLeft(rAdd(current.getLeft(), data));
    } else if (data.compareTo(current.getData()) > 0) {
        current.setRight(rAdd(current.getRight(), data));
    }
    return current;
}

public T remove(T data) {
    if (data == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: data can't be null");
    }
    BSTNode<T> dummy = new BSTNode<>(null);
    root = rRemove(root, data, dummy);
    return dummy.getData();
}

private BSTNode<T> rRemove(BSTNode<T> current, T data, BSTNode<T> dummy) {
    if (current == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Error: Data not present");
    } else if (data.compareTo(current.getData()) < 0) {
        current.setLeft(rRemove(current.getLeft(), data, dummy));
    } else if (data.compareTo(current.getData()) > 0) {
        current.setRight(rRemove(current.getRight(), data, dummy));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Data found ... ");
        dummy.setData(current.getData());
        size--;
        if (current.getRight() == null  && current.getLeft() == null) {
            if (current.equals(root)) {
                this.root = null;
            }
            return null;
        } else if (current.getLeft() != null) {
            return current.getLeft();
        } else if (current.getRight() != null) {
            return current.getRight();
        } else {
            BSTNode<T> dummy2 = new BSTNode<>(null);
            current.setRight(removeSuccessor(current.getRight(), dummy2));
            current.setData(dummy2.getData());
        }
    }
    return current;
}

private BSTNode<T> removeSuccessor(BSTNode<T> current, BSTNode<T> dummy) {
    if (current.getLeft() == null) {
        dummy.setData(current.getData());
        return current.getRight();
    } else {
        current.setLeft(removeSuccessor(current.getLeft(), dummy));
    }
}

public List<T> inorder(BSTNode<T> root) {
    ArrayList<T> inorderContents = new ArrayList<T>();
    if (root == null) {
        return inorderContents;
    }
    inorderR(inorderContents, root);
    return inorderContents;
}

private void inorderR(ArrayList<T> inorderContents, BSTNode<T> current) {
    if (current ==  null) {
        return;
    }
    inorderR(inorderContents, current.getLeft());
    inorderContents.add(current.getData());
    inorderR(inorderContents, current.getRight());
}
  
public BSTNode<T> getRoot() {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD!
    return root;
}


public int size() {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD!
    return size;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {       
    
    BST bst3 = new BST<>();

    bst3.add(1);
    bst3.add(0);
    bst3.add(5);
    bst3.add(4);
    bst3.add(2);
    bst3.add(3);

    System.out.println(bst3.inorder(bst3.getRoot() ));

    bst3.remove(1);
    System.out.println(bst3.inorder(bst3.getRoot() ));
    
}
```

}

My IDE (IntelliJ) says I am missing a return statement for my removeSuccessor(BSTNode current, BSTNode dummy) method but I expected it to recurse to the base case reinforcing the unchanged nodes.

As a result when I try and remove from a two child node it returns zero although the one child and zero child cases work .

Please can someone tell me what is wrong with my two child node remove case? Thanks, Sperling.

Comment: Just wanna point out: in rRemove the last else is never gonna be reached

Comment: Also you gonna need to return something in removeSuccessor to compile it, I think.

Comment: Many thanks wojand, figured I would need a return statement for removeSuccessor() but still confused about the pointer reinforcement used to rebuild the tree.

Comment: Finally got it. When using recursion it's crucial to know what it's meaning is. in this case it's return value is a root of the tree after the 'successor', the lowest value is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to modify the if-else by changing the conditions:

```
if (current.getLeft() != null && current.getRight() == null) {
            return current.getLeft();
        } else if (current.getRight() != null && current.getLeft() == null) {
            return current.getRight();
        }
```

instead of the same without the 2nd arguments of && in the rRemove() method.

Then, use this:

```
private BSTNode<T> removeSuccessor(BSTNode<T> current, BSTNode<T> dummy) {
    if (current.getLeft() == null) {
        dummy.setData(current.getData());
        return current.getRight();
    } else {
        current.setLeft(removeSuccessor(current.getLeft(), dummy));
        return current;
    }
}
```

Meaning of this method is as follows: delete the lowest value in the tree and return new root, as well as remember the value using dummy.

If we get nothing to the left, it's trivial - we delete current node, return getRight() and set a value to dummy.

On the other hand, if we get something to the left then we know that our current node will be the root, but  before we return it we need to remove the lowest entry to the left, and so we use the function recursively, also setting current.left to be it's return value to properly transform the tree. We pass dummy so that it can get a value when the first case occurs, and then it's communicated to the highest call (inside the first function).

It's also possible to do it without recursion:

```
private BSTNode<T> removeSuccessor2(BSTNode<T> current, BSTNode<T> dummy) {
    BSTNode<T> root = current;
    BSTNode<T> prev = null;
    while(current.getLeft() != null) {
        prev = current;
        current = current.getLeft();
    }
    /* current.getLeft == null */
    //we will delete current
    
    if (prev == null) { //no loop iterations -- current is the root
        dummy.setData(current.getData());
        return(current.getRight()); 
    }
    else {//some iterations passed, prev.getLeft() == curret
        dummy.setData(current.getData());
        prev.setLeft(current.getRight());
        return root;
    }
}
```

With dummy we return the value, the rest is transforming the tree.

Note: It doesn't work in my version for current == null. You should be able to modify it easily, though. Also, for clarity I didn't pull the dummy.setData... before if...else etc. Modify it as you wish!

Comment: Thank you wojand, I upvoted but dont have enough reputation. Hope other people find this useful. When I have reputation I will be back.

Comment: Accepted, did not see the tick mark next to it. Thanks again and sorry for being a noob!